# Show AlertView dialog from UILocalNotification

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In my app there should be an alarm when a certain distance is covered. Originally, when the conditions are met, I wanted to move the app to the foreground, show an AlertView and play a sound. Due to answers to my former post I've implemented UILOcaLnotifications and it works fine for playing an AlertSound. Even when my app is in the background and thats great. One issue remains unsolved at this moment. I really want to popup a dialog (AlertView) when the conditions are met.

At this moment the ALert message is shown at the top of the screen (like a received message or missed call) but I want to present the user with a dialog (like in the clock app)

Does anyone knows a solution to this question? Help is most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to assign alertBody and alertAction?

```
notification.alertBody = @"Some message";
notification.alertAction = @"View"; //title of action button
notification.hasAction = YES; //it YES by default
```

Comment: Yes, and it works but not with a dialog as in the clock app. I'm presented with a "sliderbar" at the top of the screen like when a textmessage is recieved. Any tips?